# Store php file output in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have php file like below

action.php?id=1

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

I have javascript code, like below

```
<script>
   var msg = [I want php file output to store in this variable]
   alert(msg);
</script>
```

How can i do this. Any way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with AJAX. For example using jQuery AJAX. [link](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/)

Example:
script.js

```
var varFromPhp = null;

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getVar.php",
    data : {'exampleVar' : 5},
    dataType : 'json', // here you can specify what format of the data you expect from the server
    success : function(data) {
        varFromPhp = data.res;
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
});
```

getVar.php

```
<?php
    $v = null;

    if (isset($_POST['exampleVar']))
        $v = $_POST['exampleVar'];

    // do some stuff with the variable and the put it into an array

    $ret = array();
    $ret['res'] = $ret;

    echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

Comment: If I have js code in another domain and php file on another. How can i get that php file output in that variable using AjAX, as you know ajax does not allow cross domain socket.

Answer (score 1):

Just output the PHP variable as a string in your JS variable if the file is parsed by the PHP parser.

For PHP 5.4 and up you can use the [short echo](http://www.php.net/echo) tags :

```
var msg = '<?= $_GET['id'] ?>';
```

Comment: But i need to get this from php file not from direct variable, In future i have to do several processes in php file

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
  <script>
       var msg = [<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>];
       alert(msg);
    </script>
```

Comment: var msg = '<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>'; This makes string

Comment: Or integer: var msg = <?php echo $_GET['id'];?>;

Comment: I want to get from php file, I have some process in php file, after that they return me some data, That i want to get in JS variable

Comment: Ok Ok . Then you can try ajax.